# Reshape array in octave / matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, reshape

I'm trying to reshape an array but I'm having some issues.
I have an array see image below and **I'm trying to get it to look like / follow the pattern in the row highlighted in yellow**.  (note: I'm **not** trying to calculate the array but reshape it so it follows a pattern)

[image: Array]

```
aa=[1:5;10:10:50;100:100:500]
aa_new=reshape(aa',[1 numel(aa)])
```

**aa_new** produces:

```
1  2  3  4  5  10  20  30  40  50  100  200  300  400  500
```

I'm trying to get:

```
1   2   3   4   5   50  40  30  20  10  100 200 300 400 500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the column numbers of every second row i.e.

```
aa(2:2:end,:) = aa(2:2:end, end:-1:1);
```

Now you're good to go with reshaping:

```
aa = reshape(aa.', 1, []);
```

Comment: In Octave, the last line can also be written as: `aa=aa.'(:).';`